# Removing decimal places after second number

Tags: powershell

I have some raw data exported from my ERP. Most of the data has two decimals, but there are a few lines contain numbers with three or more decimal places... When summing up all data with powershell I have a 0,01€ discrepancy between my ERP PDF report and sum of exported data. I tracked the discrepancy to a single number - 2.205. Powershell rounds this number to 2.2 not 2.21 as expected. If I try any other number - 2.215, 2.225 they all get rounded to 2.22, 2.23..

Why is 2.205 not treated the same???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I try any other number - 2.215, 2.225 they all get rounded to 2.22, 2.23

Are you sure about that 2.23 result? Here's my reslts when I run it:

```
PS H:\> [math]::Round(2.205,2)
2.2
PS H:\> [math]::Round(2.215,2)
2.22
PS H:\> [math]::Round(2.225,2)
2.22
PS H:\> [math]::Round(2.235,2)
2.24
PS H:\> [math]::Round(2.245,2)
2.24
```

Taken from [Scripting guy:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/rounding-numberspowershell-style/)

> Notice that here the decimal, .25, rounded down to .2. This is because the number (2) is even. In the following example, the .35 rounds up because the number (3) is odd.

To fix it, define Midpoint Routing per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0):

```
[math]::Round(2.205,2,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

.NET's default [mid-point rounding strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.MidpointRounding) is `ToEven`, meaning that `.5` values are rounded to the closest *even* integer.

**Important**: The following example use `[decimal]` numbers - as implied by number-literal suffix `d` - not `[double]`s , so as to avoid problems that stem from `[double]` values, which internally use a *binary* representation that typically does *not* have an exact *decimal* equivalent, so that a number that may *appear* to have a `5` in the relevant decimal place may actually be just above or below that exact decimal value,<sup>[1]</sup> which means that *mid-point* rounding may not apply - see [Rounding and precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.math.round#rounding-and-precision).

In the case at hand, rounding `-2.205` to 2 decimal places means that `0` is the closest *even* integer, and [`[Math]::Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Round)`(-2.205d, 2)` therefore yields `-2.20`.<sup>[2]</sup>

It sounds like you want `AwayFromZero` as the mid-point rounding strategy, which rounds to the next *higher* integer in *absolute* terms:

```sh
PS> [Math]::Round(-2.205d, 2, 'AwayFromZero')
-2.21
```

---

<sup>[1] To see if a given fractional value has an exact *decimal* representation, you can use something like the following:

`$num = [double] -2.205; '{0:F28}' -f $num`

Unless the input number is echoed with trailing *zeros* only, the given value has no exact decimal representation; `[double]` value `-2.205` does not, but `0.5` does, for instance.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that `[Math]::Round(2.225d, 2)` therefore yields `2.22`, not `2.23`, as you state in your question.</sup>